# Optimizing a query, duplicate rows that have oldest date

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I want to optimize a query but I have no idea how I could do that. Here is the table I want to query:

```
Device table:

Id    || PushId  || created

abc        aaa        10/10/13
def        aaa        10/12/13
efg        abb         9/9/12
```

The query I want is the following: I want to get duplicate PushIds and remove the oldest entry of the two from the table. This is what I have up to now (select instead of delete because I am still at the testing stage)

```
select m.* from 

(select pushId, created 
from Device 
group by pushId 
having count(*) >1)

 as m inner join Device mm on mm.pushId = m.pushId and mm.created = m.created;
```

This correctly returns the stuff that should be deleted but it is very, very slow. Is there a faster way of doing this? Is there a way to do this without a temporary table? i.e. with a single scan?

EDIT: This is MySQL i mistakenly put an MS-SQL tag in there. Apologies guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will provide the equivalent of row_number() in MySQL using @ variables. Here it locates all but the 2 most recent rows for each PushId

```
SELECT
      PushId
    , Id
    , created
FROM (
      SELECT
               @row_num :=IF(@prev_value = d.PushId,@row_num+1,1)AS RN
             , d.PushId
             , d.Id
             , d.created
             , @prev_value := d.PushId
      FROM tblDevices d
      CROSS JOIN(SELECT @row_num :=1, @prev_value :='') vars
      ORDER BY
               d.PushId
             , d.created DESC
      ) SQ
WHERE RN > 2
;
```

You can alter the outcome by changing the order (eg to ASC) to locate the oldest records. Note the cross join is used simply to "attach" 2 @ vars to each row & as there is only one row it has no impact on the actual number of records. The vars are then set within the query.

Comment: This does do exactly the same thing as the one below but correct me if i am wrong but i cannot see how this is more efficient than what i started with. There is a cross join and a variable assigning.  Just for the sake of it however, do you mind explaining how the query works exactly as i have never used row_num to help my queries?

Comment: well the cross join is insignificant here as it doesn't expand the number of records and there's no actual disk I/O involved either. The slowest part is the order but that simply cannot be avoided. There is some calculation happening to compare the prev_value and setting the values of both vars in each row, but that is quite small really, not much more than a simple case expression is effort terms.

Comment: discart my previous comment. Your solution is flawless. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number :

```
Select *
From (Select *,
             Row_Number() over(Partition by Pushid order by created) as row
      From YourTable
)z
where z.row = 1
```

Comment: that didnt work. Do you mind explaining what the thought behind your query is? Row_Number() is not a function.

Comment: Row_number() is a SQL Server function. (supported from SQL Server 2008)

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't accuracy that you use MySQL.

Comment: sorry man was my bad. I didn't put the tags properly apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There may need to be some manipulation to get it to fit into your delete statement, but try the following using the MIN function to find the lowest date+id combination, where there is more than one entry. then remove the date from the result, giving the correct id only:

```
delete from Device where id in (
    select 
         right(min(cast(cast(created as unsigned) as char(5)) + id),3)
    from Device 
    group by pushid
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use a self join, where the push id matches and the created date is greater:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.Id
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b
ON a.PushId = b.PushId
AND a.created > b.created
```

This will generate duplicates, hence using DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

if you have to delete a lot of rows (depends on your data),.., it is better to create a new table with the data you want and drop the old one. 
Delete is most expensive operation second to 'Update'

Answer (score 0):

ok, considering this is MySQL

```
 delete from Device where (push_id, created) in
 (
   select 
      pushId, 
      min(created) 
   from 
      Device 
   group by pushId 
   having count(*) >1
 )
```

Comment: I tried this myself, problem was that if there are multiple entries for example: push id: abc with many different ides and different create dates this query will only delete one entry. i.e. 

ID     PID       Created

Comment: Yes,.., it is supposed to only that (doubles) as the sample dictates (the oldest create date)
Do you want to LEAVE only 1? I will show you how, moment please

Comment: I added new reply, cannot place source code in this level of comments

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest (on most db systems)
No expenisve "group by" or "order by" needed

```
 delete from Device where (push_id, created) in
  (
   select 
     pushId, 
     created
   from 
     Device a1
   where 
     EXIST (select 1
              from Device a2
               where a1.pushId=a2.pushId
               and a2.created > a1.created
             )
    )
```

Comment: Make sure you have a nice index on (push_id) or (push_id, created) if the number of doubles is low, leave out the "created", because you always fetch rows in blocks never individual